# FFT on a specific part of an image

Tags: python, fft

I'm currently working on a project where I have to analyse an interferogram. Instead of doing an FFT on the whole image, I'd like to focus only on a small part of it (one fringe). Is it possible to define a vector along which I want my FFT to be "done"? There's also the option where I crop my interferogram, but my teacher doesn't really like this approach.

Comment: What exactly is the motivation for you, to focus on a subregion of the interferogram? Normally in processing interferometric data, you want to take as much as possible, not the other way round.

Comment: Hi, well that was also what I was going to do but our teacher told us that we should only focus on a small part.. do you have an idea on how to do it ?

Comment: The possible way: 1) Extract the sub-image from the larger image into a smaller image and FFT that. 2) Iff the FFT library used supports to specify row length independently from row stride, use set the stride to the width of the large image, the offset to the starting pixel and the row length to the length of the subrectangle to look at. 3) multiply a window function over the whole image, setting it 0 everywhere but the selection rectangle, perform the FFT over the whole image, then crop the result to the subimage dimensions.

Comment: Ok yes I think I’ll go with option number 3 thanks !